# Prometheus Docker fails to start with `Template: (dynamic): parse: template: :10: undefined variable "$labels"`

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to run Prometheus on Nomad. Everything things look fine but when I add an alert rule with templating in `annotations` it fails.

here is a simple alert rule:

```yaml
groups:
- name: alertmanager.rules
  rules:
  - alert: AlertmanagerDown
    expr: up{job="alertmanager"} == 0
    for: 1s
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      description: 'Alertmanager on {{ $labels.role }} instance {{ $labels.node }} has not produced any metrics for 5 minutes'
      summary: 'Alertmanager is down on {{ $labels.role }} instance {{ $labels.node }}'
```

Container fails with `Template: (dynamic): parse: template: :10: undefined variable "$labels"`

If I remove `annotations` section it starts without any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to set `left_delimiter` and `right_delimiter` to something other than `{{` and `}}`
https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/template.html#left_delimiter

Comment: Could you send the change you di I got the same error  ?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue when deploying Prometheus.
Deploying Prometheus via a helm chart will have an issue as the same delimiters `({{` and `}})` are used both by helm templating and the alerting templating in Prometheus.

For my case, the solution is:

```
  recordType: ALARM
  managedObjectInstance: "Namespace={{ "{{" }} $labels.app_kubernetes_io_instance }},Instance={{ "{{" }} $labels.instance }}"
```

More example can be found [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/d6c45e97eca55e6212ef8acf546b45aa7851c72e/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus/rules-1.14/node-exporter.yaml).