# How to fix the error undefined variable "$labels"in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager

I used this alret

```
        - alert: my alert
          expr: status{status="ERROR"}
          for: 30m
          labels:
            severity: WARNING   
          annotations:
            myData: "{{ $labels.myData }}"
            myData2: "{{ $labels.myData2 }}"
```

I got an error
ERROR - templates/: parse error in "prometheus/templates/alertmanager-prometheusRule.yaml": template: prometheus/templates/alertmanager-prometheusRule.yaml:419: undefined variable "$labels"

I saw the same issue in

[Prometheus Docker fails to start with `Template: (dynamic): parse: template: :10: undefined variable "$labels"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066196/prometheus-docker-fails-to-start-with-template-dynamic-parse-template-10)

but I didn't understand how to solve it

in the configuration I used this data

```
text: "{{ range .Alerts -}}{{ .Annotations.myData }}{{ .Annotations.myData2}}{{ end-}}"
```

The error is from helm  lint

Comment: What happens if you change:

```myData: "{{ $labels.myData}}"```

To:

```description: "{{ $labels.myData}}"```

Comment: @Saf - I have two annotation in my keys . I will update my question . did you mean to change only the myData to description. but if I have two annotations what I can do. also I get this data in the text like Annotations.myData

Comment: @saf - in the answer of the question he wrote 0

Had to set left_delimiter and right_delimiter what does it mean ?

Comment: Not a clue on the left_delimiter stuff, it doesn't make sense to me. Do you have any other working alerts that use the format "myData: "<<something>>" ? I've never seen that before but that doesn't mean it doesn't work, just my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems you are deploying your Prometheus setup via a helm chart.
This causes an issue as the same delimiters (`{{` and `}}`) are used both by helm templating and the alerting templating in Prometheus.

The `{{ $labels.myData }}` has to reach prometheus config intact, so helm must not process it.

The simplest way would be to use:

```
{{ "{{" }} $labels.myData }}
```

The `{{ "{{" }}` block will be processed by helm and will produce `{{` as a result with rest of the line not being altered and will get you the result you need.

Comment: I tried I didn't get an error but the output was myData: {{ $labels.myData}}

Comment: and yes The Prometheus setup is with a helm chart

Comment: I did something like this myData: '{{ "{{" }} $labels.myData }}'

Comment: I tried also ` {{ $labels.myData }} ` it pass the lint but i didn't get the data

Comment: Right answer !! upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [awenser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64694592/15545196)

OR

you can simply instead of using double qoutes `""`, use the single-qoutes `''`

e.g. here would be like:

```
annotations:
  myData: '{{ $labels.myData }}'
  myData2: '{{ $labels.myData2 }}'
```

source: [Prometheus Docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/notification_examples/)

Comment: This will not work, as the issue here is that helm will intercept and process it before it reaches prometheus config

Answer (score 1):

Kind of the same answer as @bjakubski, but with examples:

I would suggest doing the same way as the official Prometheus helm chart is doing to pass alerts:

```yaml
description: Filesystem on {{`{{`}} $labels.device {{`}}`}} at {{`{{`}} $labels.instance {{`}}`}} has only {{`{{`}} printf "%.2f" $value {{`}}`}}% available space left and is filling up.
```

They have plenty of examples in the repository.

Link:
https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/d6c45e97eca55e6212ef8acf546b45aa7851c72e/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus/rules-1.14/node-exporter.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python script to make @bjakubski's change in bulk on a file:

```
import sys
import re

f = sys.argv[1]

regex = re.compile(r"(\{\{.*?\}\})")

with open (f, "r") as myfile:
     s=myfile.read()

ret = regex.sub(lambda x:x.group(1)[0:2]+' "{{" }}'+ x.group(1)[2:],s)

print ret
```